# glReadPixels invalid use of member (did you forget the '&' ?)

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

whay do I get this error when I attempt to execute this qt opengl code?

```
    // 4 bytes per pixel (RGBA), 1x1 bitmap
    QVector<unsigned char> pixels( 1 * 1 * 4 );
    glReadPixels( x, height - y, 1, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &pixels[0]);

    qDebug() << "r: " << (int)pixels[0];
    qDebug() << "g: "   << (int)pixels[1];
    qDebug() << "b: "   << (int)pixels[2];
    qDebug() << "a: "   << (int)pixels[3];
```

could you bring me a correct example of it? and I am also looking for the reverse function that pastes an array of colors to screen pixels.

Comment: Try `unsigned char pixels[4]`.

Comment: What's the **exact** error you get?

Comment: glReadPixels invalid use of member (did you forget the '&' ?)

Comment: @user1596226 Did you try my suggestion? Did you get the same error?

Answer (score 3):

QVector is a particular kind of code. `operator[]` exists in two variants: A const and a modifiable variant. And the way which one operator is used can become rather obscure.

Anyway, you shouldn't use a QVector in your case anyway: Far too much overhead (calling the constructor, allocating the internal memory, etc.). Use a simple, fixed size, scoped array:

```
// 4 bytes per pixel (RGBA), 1x1 bitmap
GLubyte pixels[4];
glReadPixels( x, height - y, 1, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

qDebug() << "r: " << (int)pixels[0];
qDebug() << "g: "   << (int)pixels[1];
qDebug() << "b: "   << (int)pixels[2];
qDebug() << "a: "   << (int)pixels[3];
```

Answer (score 1):

Shot in the dark, but since you added the qt tag to your question: is `height` supposed to be `QGLWidget::height()`? If so, you need to actually call the method :)

```
glReadPixels( x, height() - y, 1, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
```

Comment: Good point, unless height is actually a variable which is the widget height (`height = QGLWidget::height();`).